# Anchor tag click doesn't work with return true statement in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery for anchor tag in which it calls for ajax first time and then when the success is returned it calls click again.  On the second call it returns true but the anchor link doesn't work.

Below is my code

Html:

```
 <a href="#" class="test-link" target="_blank">test</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
  $('.test-link').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('test')){
      $(this).removeClass('test');
      return true;
    } else {

      $.ajax({
      ...
      ...
      success : function(data) {
          $('.test-link').attr('href',data.url).addClass('test').click(); 
      }
      });
      return false;
    }
 });
```

This doesn't work for me and i also tried using preventDefault();  but no use.

Note : On the very first click, it calls the ajax and when it is a success, it sets the url of anchor and class and then calls the click again,
  **But the click doesn't navigate to other page.**

Comment: Can't you just say `window.location = data.url;`?

Comment: No i want to open the page in new tab, Check out the target is "_blank".

Answer (score 1):

Triggering the click event of an anchor **does not redirect** to the page specified automatically.

You have to click the link **explicitly** to navigate to a different page..

You can use

```
window.open('','','width=200,height=100') ; // instead`
```

You can try this approach

```
if ($(this).hasClass('test')){
    $(this).removeClass('test');

    window.open('','','width=200,height=100')
}
```

Comment: I already tried this .  window.open have limitations..  Many browser blocks the popup which i dont want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.open()`, but as far as getting `click()` to work you can do this:

```
$('.test-link').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('test')){
        $(this).removeClass('test').off('click'); // unbind click handler
        this.click();                             // call native click()
    } else {
      $.ajax({
      ...
      ...
      success : function(data) {
          $('.test-link').attr('href',data.url).addClass('test').click(); 
      }
      });
      return false;
    }
 });
```

Using `this.click()` will directly call the DOM element's `click()` method rather than the jQuery `click()` method - I've found in the past this will cause the default behaviour for a link to actually work (i.e., it will navigate to the specified url), whereas the jQuery `click()` method will execute the handler you've assigned but not actually navigate.

But also you need to unbind the click handler so that it doesn't go into an endless loop. Which means from then on the link will always open that same URL in a new tab, it won't make further Ajax requests. Is that acceptable?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pdwt8/1/

Comment: I was stuck on this probably 1 day. Nowhere in the web found your solution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This opens the page in new tab not in pop-up

```
  window.open(url,'_blank');
```

I think it should be,

```
if ($(this).hasClass('test')){
$(this).removeClass('test');

window.open($(this).text(),'_blank');
}
```